# CONVERT various date-like strings (varchar) to one DATE field

Tags: sql, regex, sql-server-2008

Consider a varchar field (`ShipDate`) that gets date-like strings written to it.  These strings come from multiple third-party systems in various formats (over which I, apparently, have no control =/).

I decided to create a view that converts this `varchar` field to `DATE` so that I can query it easily (and filter out some other records / fields that I don't care about).

So far I see two formats coming in: YYYYMMDD (which is fine, I can just a a straight `CONVERT`) and MM/DD/YYYY, which causes an error:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

This changes my conversion from a simple `CONVERT(DATE, ShipDate, 1)` to:

```
CONVERT (DATE,
(CASE 
    WHEN ShipDate LIKE '_/__/____' THEN SUBSTRING(ShipDate, 6, 4) + '0' + SUBSTRING(ShipDate, 1, 1) + SUBSTRING(ShipDate, 3, 2)--M/DD/YYYY
    WHEN ShipDate LIKE '__/_/____' THEN SUBSTRING(ShipDate, 6, 4) + SUBSTRING(ShipDate, 1, 2) + '0' + SUBSTRING(ShipDate, 4, 1)--MM/D/YYYY
    WHEN ShipDate LIKE '_/_/____' THEN SUBSTRING(ShipDate, 5, 4) +  '0' + SUBSTRING(ShipDate, 1, 1) + '0' + SUBSTRING(ShipDate, 3, 1)--M/D/YYYY
    ELSE ShipDate --For the YYYYMMDD dates
END), 1) --End of CONVERT
```

**Is there a better way to do the above SQL statement?** I could potentially get *even more* date-like string formats as time goes on, so the above example could get pretty awful (I tagged this question with [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) in case that could reduce the size of the case statement).

**Or, is there a way to handle this problem as the records come in**, avoiding the view altogether?  I'm not too familiar with Triggers / SP's, but if that's a good option I'm willing to go that route =)

**Or, some other method that is commonly used to solve this problem?**  Just curious at this point.  I'm a .NET programmer, but end up helping out with SQL work because I have *some* experience, so I'm pretty new to anything even kind of advanced in SQL.

Comment: Commence flaming about storing strings as dates, I'll ***very gladly*** pass them on to the huge shipping companies whose software does this inane thing =)

Comment: You can only really solve for *known* variations on standard formats. One key is to stop, right now, allowing free-text form entry for dates. You need to take control of what gets into your database, even if you need to continue using `VARCHAR` to store them. You can only really use RegEx in SQL Server if you implement CLR (and I have done this), you won't be able to do it natively.

Comment: Triggers would be exactly the same as the view; you'd still have to manually edit them. I have the same problem from suppliers and have a staging table for each inbound file. This then has a view on top of it to force all data to be database standard. You don't have to do anything until it breaks.

Comment: @Aaron That is really good advice, thanks!  I'm waiting to hear back from FedEx to see if they'll stop letting people enter whatever junk they want into that field (their software doesn't use that field, it just writes to to our database - so they are less than concerned).  Also, that's good knowledge to have about regex

Comment: So does FedEx write directly to your database? If they send you files you could always scrub them *before* loading by making that step a part of the existing ETL/ELT process. If they call you directly via stored procedure or web service then you have a similar opportunity to clean the data *before* it gets into your system.

Comment: @Aaron actually, we have FedEx shipping station PCs here locally that write to the SQL database via ODBC connection (they just do a straight `INSERT` after each order.)  But, maybe I *could* scrub the entries as they're written.  I'll have to see what kind of control we have over the `INSERT` statement

Comment: You could also use an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger. The apps will never know. :-)

Comment: @Aaron Wow!  I have not heard of that, that's sneaky =)  Thanks for taking the time to look at this man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the known formats are always M then D, and the separators are always /, why not just parse for the slashes? Also, why are you using `,1)` in your `CONVERT`? All of the above formats seemed to convert fine for me without it:

```
WITH x(ShipDate) AS
(
    SELECT '5/12/2011'
    UNION ALL SELECT '05/5/2012'
    UNION ALL SELECT '05/05/2012'
)
SELECT CONVERT (DATE, ShipDate) FROM x;
```

Comment: And that's why I shouldn't be doing the SQL stuff here =).  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the `date_style` parameter for `CONVERT`. That's really for converting in the other direction. You should be able to just use: `CAST(some_string AS DATE)`.

You might have some problems if you start getting dates in the DD/MM/YYYY format though. Of course, if they're being all mixed together then there's no way to solve that issue anyway, since even you can't know whether 4/1/2011 is April 1st or January 4th.

Comment: Shows what I know, thanks!  I guess if they start sending dates as DD/MM/YYYY that's when things will get *really* interesting =)

Answer (score 1):

You say you can work with YYYYMMDD?

But MM/DD/YYYY is giving you problems.  Then perhaps you can do this:

```
CONVERT(varchar(8),CAST('MM/DD/YYYY' as datetime),112) = YYYYMMDD
```

Answer (score 1):

my reaction would be to add a proper date column, then implement a trigger that does the conversion into that date column.

you could then manually fix up any that failed to convert, and those records would still have values, unlike the view solution.

Comment: I wouldn't take any chances that the data would fail to insert.  I presume since it's an outside company that getting this data (period) is more important than getting it in the right format.  If you use a trigger, *at least* be careful enough to copy any disqualified records to an audit table so you can manually review/correct them and try to insert again.

Comment: @kuru I see Randy's point though.  I suppose I could check failure logs on the trigger, so if a new date format started breaking the trigger, I would be warned to go fix it

Comment: @jadarnel27 -- yeah, that's what I meant.  From the sounds of it, it won't be any big surprise if you start seeing a new date format.  So let the trigger log the record, and that will allow you to update your trigger to handle it, and then try to insert again.

Comment: @kuru: whoops, I misread your comment =)  Thanks for the advice